# Поиск дат в таблице по содержащемуся в них числу

Tags: python, django, datetime

У меня есть таблица с датами в формате "%Y-%m-%d". Каждая дата присваевается определеннному документу и отображается на странице сайта в формате "%d.%m.%Y". Мне нужно сдлеать так, чтобы когда пользователь вводил число в строку поиска на этой странице, ему отображались все даты. Например, есть даты 13.01.2023,12.01.2023,20.05.2023.Если пользователь вводит "1", то отображаются 13.01.2023 и 12.01.2023, если  "5.2" то 20.05.2023 и т.д.
Пока написала поиск только для случая, когда пользовательно вводит дату полностью

```
if re.match("\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}", request.GET['search[value]']):
            dataDocument=dataDocument.filter(data="{:%Y-%m-%d}".format(datetime.strptime(request.GET['search[value]'], "%d.%m.%Y")), type__description='Дата')
            doc1 = Cdocuments.objects.filter(pk__in=dataDocument.values_list('document', flat=True))
            expertise = expertise.filter(pk__in=doc1.values_list('expertise', flat=True))
```